# What causes the screw modifier to fail and create black 2d slice from a bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I am trying to create a plate using a Bezier curve as the profile then use the screw modifier to create the full outline as in this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/vyZOZrtkzz8?t=329), when I apply the screw modifier to the curve that I have created it makes a black 2d horizontal slice instead of the full 3d plate outline.

[image: Bezier curve for plate outline]
This shows the bezier curve I have drawn

[image: failed screw modification]
This shows what happens after the screw modifier is applied

I tried using a line drawn with Nurbs Curve and was able to apply the screw modifier to create a 3d object.

[image: Nurbs Curve with screw modifier]

I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong, any help that you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Edit -

[image: Explanation for answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've scaled the curve to 0 in one dimension or another, *in Object mode*, to flatten it. If the *object* carries that transform, it still will, after being modified. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > Apply the scale of your curve.

Think twice, every time you scale in Object mode during modelling. Prefer to do it in Edit mode.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it, I have been trying to figure that out for a couple of hours now